# React: unable to fetch state inside setInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I have a button on which I need to call a setInterval but if the interval is already set then I don't want to initiate another setInterval.

So this is how I have implemented it ():

```
export default function App() {
  const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState(null);

  const startInterval = () => {
    console.log("inside startInterval", intervalId);
    if (!intervalId) {
      console.log("starting Interval", intervalId);
      const _intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        console.log("Interval Id inside setInterval is", intervalId);
      }, 2 * 1000);
      setIntervalId(_intervalId);
    } else {
      console.log("Rejecting set interval");
    }
  };

  const onBtnClick = () => {
    console.log("btn clicked");
    // make API call
    startInterval();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={onBtnClick}>Click Me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

but inside setInterval I always get to see the default value of state i.e. null in my case.
How can I access the latest value inside setInterval?

[Click here to go to Live Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-austin-r2uof?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working. While the *log* shows the `intervalId` as `null`, that's only because the function that the interval closes over was initialized when the `intervalId` was indeed `null`.

A variable declared with `const` can't be reassigned; the `intervalId` starts out as `null` during the render when the button is clicked, and the `startInterval` function closes over that `null`. When `startInterval` is called, and the anonymous callback is declared:

```
() => {
  console.log("Interval Id inside setInterval is", intervalId);
}
```

it still closes over the `null` `intervalId`.

If you wanted to see the interval ID inside the callback, use a ref instead.

```
const intervalIdRef = useRef();
// ...
intervalIdRef.current = setInterval(() => {
  console.log("Interval Id inside setInterval is", intervalIdRef.current);
}, 2 * 1000);
```

and use `intervalIdRef.current` everywhere it's needed instead of `intervalId`.

Comment: If I want to access reduxState inside setInterval, then what should I do?

Comment: Your question doesn't contain Redux anywhere, but if you wanted to access it, it looks pretty simple: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-5-ui-react#passing-the-store-with-provider

Comment: you mean using providers I can access Redux inside setInterval?

Comment: You can also use this method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986366/accessing-redux-store-inside-functions